# Carrying my laptop to abroad from India

Tags: usa, india, electronic-items

When I was 14 I was going to USA with my family, my father was carrying his laptop, I was also carrying it but my dad was strictly not allowing that. Which is the solution to carry my laptop from India to abroad?

Comment: Your dad doesn't let you carry his laptop? Or you now have your own laptop? It's a little unclear what you're asking, if you could edit it a bit please.

Comment: I have traveled with a laptop from the US to India dozens of times, and never had any problems. In some cases, there has been an incoming security check though no customs scrutiny. As other answers mention, it's best to keep it with you person.

Answer (score 3):

**You can carry your laptop in any form of baggage** as long as you are within the permissible limits and no explicit clauses are set by the airline for the carrying of laptops. I am aware of none.

**Ideally people carry them within their handbag or cabin luggage** as it is a fragile item. Most international airlines also allow you to carry a separate laptop shoulder bag in addition to cabin luggage but you will have to confirm this.

When it comes to the security gate, you will be required to remove your laptop from your bag for scanning separately from your bag. This is standard, but with too much paranoia in the air, travellers to the US may be subjected to more exciting tests! I don't know!

---

If you are travelling to the US as a student, and I might be wrong, but it might actually be better to buy one there once you get there. Not for the reasons you ask in your question, but instead for better price deals on slightly better hardware and local warranty, etc. Just a suggestion, your choice!

Answer (score 2):

There is no restriction on carrying laptop from India to USA, as long as you are meeting the baggage limitations.

It is [advised](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/packing-tip) not to keep your laptop in checked-in baggage. You should carry your laptop with your carry-on baggage. You're free to keep it inside your carry on OR carry it as a second item, apart from your normal carry-on luggage.