# Laptop customs in India

Tags: india, customs-and-immigration

When I checked on the customs website (CBEC) then it was saying that one laptop is allowed as duty free if any passenger is at the age of 18 years and above. The problem is that I am 15 years old, if I carry that to abroad and came back with that, I have to pay that. What is the solution of carrying laptop without paying customs duty and where to get it?

Comment: Are you a Indian resident or a foreigner residing in India? Are you traveling alone?

Comment: possible dublicate http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/can-i-take-both-a-laptop-and-a-tablet-in-my-carry-on-bag-when-going-to-india and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/carrying-my-laptop-to-abroad-from-india
you have already asked this question

Comment: India MAY do things differently, but - If you mean by "...  if I carry that to abroad and came back with that,  ..." that you have the laptop already and are taking it with you and bringing it back again then, in most countries you can show it to customs when you leave and receive an acjknowldgement that it is already yours and no duty would be payable.

Comment: Well, first you scatter rose petals on your laptop, then light a candle and.. oh wait, not that kind of customs?

Comment: @DJClayworth Don't ever give up the day job, to become a comedian.

Answer (score 2):

Duty-free import only applies if you are bringing something into the country that you bought outside it. If you take a laptop out of the country and bring it back, that isn't import and you don't have to pay duty.

Now the trouble is, you have to convince customs officials that you did in fact take it out of the country. Much of the time they may take your word for it, or not even ask. I've never had any trouble (though I've never travelled through Indian customs). If you have the receipt, or a guarantee document indicating where it was bought, that should work. Alternatively there may be a way to register your laptop on the way out of the country with customs, or at least record the fact that it was taken out. You will be less likely to have trouble if the laptop doesn't look brand new, and has personal stuff on it.